# Android Virtual Device can't be started - Intel HAXM can't be installed

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, virtualization, haxm

I'd really appreciate it if somebody could help. I pretty much did everything possible that I know.
Still, I'm stuck with starting an AVD. When I try to start the virtual device I get the following warning

[image: warning]

I tried what it said and rebooted the system, but nothing changed.
I even tried to disable the **Hyper-V** from **Windows Features** as in this picture and restarted the windows and still, nothing changed.

[image: picture]
PS. The Virtualization Technology in BIOS is **enabled**.
Neither installing [Intel® HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) from the official website works

[image: (Error Message)]

nor installing it from [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) works

[image: (Error message)]

### **System Information**

OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
System Manufacturer: LENOVO
System Model: 80SM
System Type: x64-based PC
Processor: [Intel® Core™ i7-6500U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/products/88194/Intel-Core-i7-6500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz)
BIOS Mode: UEFI
Secure Boot State: On
Installed Physical Memory (RAM): 12.0 GB
Virtualization-based security: Running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Hyper-V launch, remove all Hyper-V features and set Registry Keys to disable virtualization-based security:

```
D:\> bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

D:\> dism /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All /NoRestart

D:\> reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA /v LsaCfgFlags /d 0 /f /t REG_DWORD

D:\> reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Device Guard" /v EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity /d 0 /f /t REG_DWORD
```

Delete the Credential Guard and the VBS UEFI variables. To mount the UEFI partition determine an unused drive letter and set the environment Variable FREE_MOUNT_VOL_DRIVELETTER.

```
D:\> set FREE_MOUNT_VOL_DRIVELETTER=L:
D:\> mountvol %FREE_MOUNT_VOL_DRIVELETTER% /s
D:\> copy C:\WINDOWS\System32\SecConfig.efi L:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y
D:\> bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DG" /application osloader
D:\> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"
D:\> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}
D:\> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS
D:\> bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=%FREE_MOUNT_VOL_DRIVELETTER%
D:\> mountvol %FREE_MOUNT_VOL_DRIVELETTER% /d
D:\> shutdown /t 0 /r
```

At next boot time, this forces two prompts to disable Credentials Guard and virtualization-based security. **Accept both with F3.**

**Source [Blog](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/windows-disable-device-guard-virtualization-based-security/) by [Michael](https://michlstechblog.info/blog/).**

Answer (score 1):

You can't run AVD if you have another virtual machine running.  They conflict with each other. You have to run one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) What virtual machine? I did have VMWare installed but I uninstalled it before a couple of days.

Comment: I don't know, I'm not on your box.  But that error means you're running a VM (not just have one installed, actively running).  The processor only allows one hypervisor at a time.